# How to check if content is same in div block?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show a new HTML form with inputs and buttons only if it's not the same as the form on the page. Also, this method should ignore the entered value and don't refresh it if the user typed something. The method is working inside the interval. Currently, it's doesn't work as expected. It redraws form even if nothing changed.

This is method I'm trying to fix.

```
loadView : function (name, selector = $("#content")) {
            let url = 'v/' + name + '.html';
            let temp = selector.html();
            $.get(url, function (response) {
                if(response != temp) /// prevent redrawing if already is the same
                {
                    console.log("response and temp isn't same"); 
                    selector.html(response);
                }
            });
        }
```

This is HTML I have issue with

```
Info: <input type="text" id="info" value="">
<button onclick="action.doAction();">Action</button>
```

I expect script loads the forms that the user can insert his info, and If form changes it will reload the whole selector. I still need to get a new form even if it's the same. I need to redraw only if there are changes because user info removes after each redraw.

Comment: Can't you compare `name` instead? Seems like the only thing that is variable in the URL. So if `name` doesn't change, the result from the ajax call shouldn't change either, I suppose?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to do. Does your problem exist only when user has typed something inside the textbox? can you print/check the values of response & temp in loadView function where you are trying to check they are different, eg: `console.log("response: " + response, "\r\ntemp: " + temp)` to see whats exactly inside them (may be some formatting html, empty/newline chars, or upper/lower case difference)?

Comment: @Jeto server might return different form in response to same url request.

Comment: @S.Serpooshan it redraw even if nothing typed. That's the problem. Looks like FireFox changes HTML and adds some new lines and edits input from `<input type="text">` to `<input type="text" />` So the content isn't same.

Comment: @NikitaCunskis so, as a quick workaround you may consider to replace some chars like as white space or "/" with empty string before comparing those strings. but this is not a good method. You may also use another method to know if form should be updated, eg using a version number or date-time code...